# Не подгружается CSS при разбиении кода PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, помогите с проблемой, над которой потратил уже не один час, читал много всякого, но подобного не нашел... Это код регистрации на сайте, все работает, но если его вот так разбить, то css не подгружается... если код совместим, то все работает хорошо. Все бы ничего, но я, как видно по html форме, хочу передать значение setcookie() и при успешной регистрации вместо - с помощью header('location:') - должно перебросить на другую страницу. Но, как известно, это вызываются до любых html тегов и любого вывода данных. header() я, конечно, могу изменить на

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://my-site.ru">';
```

но как мне быть с setcokie()? Помогите.

```
<?php include 'blocks/db.php';
function clearText($test){
    return mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($test)));
}
?><?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $login = clearText($_POST['login']);
    $pass = clearText($_POST['pass']);
    $clear_pass = clearText($_POST['clear_pass']);
    $name = clearText($_POST['name']);
    $surname = clearText($_POST['surname']);
    $pol = $_POST['pol'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    $date_reg = date('d.m.Y  H:i');
    if(!empty($login)&&!empty($pass)&&isset($check)&&$pass==$clear_pass){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
        if(!$query) exit(mysql_error().' ошибка, попробуйте позже!');
        $res = mysql_result($query, 0);
        if($res == 0){
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login, password, date_reg, 
                                                            name, surname, pol) 
                               VALUES ('$login', '$pass', '$date_reg', '$name', 
                                                          '$surname', '$pol')");
            if($query){
                echo 'Регистрация прошла успешно!';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HEAD>
  <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
  <TITLE>Регистрация</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV id="head">Общение на Slepeek.ru</DIV>
<div id='reg' ><b>Регистрация</b></div>

<?php // продолжения кода
            }elseif(!$query){
                echo 'Ошибка при добавлении данный. Попробуйте позднее.';
            }

        }elseif($res > 0){
            echo "<div id='error'>Логин занят, пожалуйста, выберите другой.</div>";
        }
    }elseif(empty($login)&&empty($pass)){
        echo "<div id='error'>Вы не заполнили обязательные поля!</div>";
    }elseif(empty($login)){
        echo "<div id='error'>Укажите логин!</div>";
    }elseif(empty($pass)){
        echo "<div id='error'>Укажите пароль!</div>";
    }elseif($pass!=$clear_pass){
        echo "<div id='error'>Пароли не совпадают!</div>";
    }elseif(!isset($check)){
        echo "<div id='error'>Необходимо согласиться с правилами!</div>";
    }
}
?>
<center>Обязательные поля</center>
   <hr align="center" color="#3366FF" noshade="noshade"/>
<p>
  <FORM action = '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method = 'POST'>
   <font color='red'>*</font>Введите логин:<br>
   <INPUT type = 'text' name = 'login' value = "<?=$_COOKIE['login'];?>"><br>
   <font color='red'>*</font>Введите пароль:<br>
   <INPUT type = 'password' name = 'pass' value = "<?=$_COOKIE['pass'];?>"><br>
   <font color='red'>*</font>Подтвердите пароль:<br>
   <INPUT type = 'password' name = 'clear_pass'><br>
</p>
<center>Личные данные</center>
   <hr align="center" color="#3366FF" noshade="noshade"/>
<p> 
    Ваше имя:<br>
    <INPUT type = 'text' name = 'name'><br>
    Ваша фамилия:<br>
    <INPUT type = 'text' name = 'surname'><br>
    Ваш пол:<br>
    <SELECT name = 'pol'>
    <option value="------" selected="selected">------</option>
    <option value="Мужской">Мужской</option>
    <option value="Женский">Женский</option>
    </SELECT><br>
    <INPUT type = 'checkbox' name = 'check'> Соглашение с пользовательскими <a href='#'>правилами</a>.<br>
    <INPUT type = 'submit' value = 'Зарегистрироваться' class="button">
  </FORM>
</p>

<a href='#'>Назад</a><br>
<DIV id='footer'><a href='index.php'>На главную</a></div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: ПРЕКРАТИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПИСАТЬ ХТМЛ-ТЕГИ КАПСОМ :'-( И с одинарными кавычками. Это стиль 1993 года примерно.

Comment: каждый пишет как ему удобно) из-за этого ошибок нет ) а читабельность, по крайней мере для меня, удобней)

Comment: @NoProblems, у вас XHTML Strict.
В этом стандарте имена тегов _должны быть_ написаны в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Мой первый сайт прям.

Answer (score 3):

Код вообще бы переписать. Не знаю чего вы не понимаете именно, но может вам такие штуки помогут

```
$message1 = '';
if (что-то успешно/неуспешно)
  $message1 = 'что-то успешно/неуспешно';

if (что-то случилось и надо сохранить куку) {
  setcookie(...)
  header('Location: ...');
  exit; // не забывайте exit, иначе переадресация произойдет только после полной загрузки
}

?><!DOCTYPE ...> и так далее
```

А дальше в хтмл:

```
<? echo $message1; ?>
```

Я к чему: все, что надо выводить в хтмл, загоняйте в переменные, а потом выводите. Тогда никаких проблем в header'ами не будет.

Comment: спасибо, завтра по пробую) у меня 6 утра, башка не варит уже

Comment: что-то успешно/неуспешно :DDD

Comment: ничего не получилось)

Comment: css не то что не подгружается, а где бы не проходил разрыв кода php? все что между разрывом браузер не видит, даже в исходном коде нет... соответственно, просто не находит строку <link> ведущию на css стили (

Comment: Так вынесите его из условия-то)) 

Вот эту часть(*см. ниже*) переместите вниз, так чтоб ее не разбивал хтмл. Когда поймете, как работать с переменными - сами сообразите, что не так. Пока вам этого хватит.
    
    if($query){
      echo 'Регистрация прошла успешно!';

Comment: спасибо)) получилось разобраться